# Add classpath to spring boot in Intellij

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Usually spring boot would restart when files in the classpath change. But when I ran spring boot in intellij and changed some contents in `src/main/resources/static/templates/index.html`, I found that spring boot didn't restart. After debugging for a while, I found that the path I just mentioned was not part of classpath. The related classpaths are the corresponding output paths.

```
build/classes/main/
build/resources/main/
```

So my question is, can I add `src/main` to classpath in intellij so spring boot will auto restart the server when changes are made? It might not be hard to do this in commandline, but I didn't find a way to achieve this in Intellij.